# lmer mixte multilevel regression not working on data without noise

Tags: r, regression, lme4

I there. I am encountering some problems with the lmer function. I am trying to test it on simple data, and I don't get what I expected but warnings and errors.
Here is the example

```
library(lme4)
library(lme4)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(115)
Nid = 20
Nx = 15
b <- 0
a <- 0.5

test <- data.table(ID = rep(LETTERS[1:Nid],each = Nx), X = rep(1:Nx,Nid))
test[,Y := rnorm(1,mean = b,sd = 1) + rnorm(1,mean = a,sd = 1*a)*X, by = ID]
```

This is a set of individual with Y having a random intercept and slope with X

```
fitnonmixte <- lm(Y~X,data = test)
summary(fitnonmixte)
fitmixte <- lmer(Y~X + (1 + X |ID),data = test,REML = T)
summary(fitmixte)
```

The fit with lmer gives me some warnings that I don't understand:

```
Warning messages:
1: In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, getStart(start, rho$lower, rho$pp),  :
  convergence code 3 from bobyqa: bobyqa -- a trust region step failed to reduce q
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 2 negative eigenvalues
```

and doesn't give better result than the simple regression. Increasing thenumber of individual doesn't seem to change the behavior.
When I want to do :

```
test <- data.table(ID = rep(LETTERS[1:Nid],each = Nx), X = rep(1:Nx,Nid))
test[,Y := rnorm(1,mean = b,sd = 2) + rnorm(1,mean = a,sd = 2*a)*X, by = ID]
fitmixte <- lmer(Y~X + (1 + X |ID),data = test,REML = T)
```

I get:

```
Error in fn(x, ...) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite
```

that I don't understand... 
I realized after that if I add noise to the data

```
test <- data.table(ID = rep(LETTERS[1:Nid],each = Nx), X = rep(1:Nx,Nid))
test[,Y := rnorm(1,mean = b,sd = 2) + rnorm(1,mean = a,sd = 2*a)*X + rnorm(.N,mean = 0,sd = 1), by = ID]
```

everything works fine. So why can't lmer give a proper result on data with no noise ? Is there a way to avoid that behavior ? What are the meaning of the errors ?

Thank you for your help !